# How to integrate react-intl-tel-input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, web-development-server

Hello I am new in ReactJS and I have to implement `react-intl-tel-input` for taking phone number from all over the world but while integration I was facing some issues. When I write this code:

```
<IntlTelInput
  containerClassName="intl-tel-input"
  inputClassName="form-control"
  name="mobile"
  placeholder="Enter Your Number" 
  input
  type="tel"
  value={this.state.phoneNumber}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
```

I was not able to access `this.handleChange` but When I write my normal code like this

```
<input
  type="tel"
  id="phone"
  name="mobile"
  placeholder="Enter Your Number"
  required
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

I was able to access `this.handleChange` and my code work perfectly but I was unable to take country code. If anyone know the solution please help. I was getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'phoneNumber')
```

This is my complete code.

---

Login.js

```
import React from 'react'
import firebase from './firebase'
import 'firebase/auth';
import "./App.css";
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";
import IntlTelInput from 'react-intl-tel-input';
import 'react-intl-tel-input/dist/main.css';


class Login extends React.Component {

  handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log (e)
    const { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
     
    })
    console.log (value)
    this.setState({ phoneNumber: value }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.phoneNumber);
    });
  }
  configureCaptcha = () =>{
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response) => {

        // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.

        this.onSignInSubmit();
        console.log("Recaptca varified")
      },
      //  defaultCountry: "IN"
     }
    );
  }
  onSignInSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.configureCaptcha()
    const phoneNumber = this.state.mobile
    console.log(phoneNumber)
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
    get(child(dbRef, `Users/${phoneNumber}`)).then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)

          .then((confirmationResult) => {

            window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;

            alert('An OTP has been sent to your registered mobile number')
            localStorage.setItem("Phone_No", phoneNumber)
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('Phone_No'));

          }).catch((error) => {

            console.error(error);
            alert("Oops! Some error occured. Please try again.")
          });
      }
      else {
        alert('Sorry, this mobile number is not registered with us. Please use your registered mobile number.');
      }

    })
  }
  onSubmitOTP = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const code = this.state.otp
    console.log(code)
    window.confirmationResult.confirm(code).then((result) => {
      // User signed in successfully.
      const Users = result.user;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(Users))
      this.props.history.push("/home");
    }).catch((error) => {
      alert("You have entered wrong code")
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Main-header">
        <img src="./55k-logo.png" alt="Company Logo" style={{ height: "80px", width: "200px" }} />
        <br />
        <div>
          <h2>Login Form</h2>
          <p>Limtless Water. From Unlimited Air.</p>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSignInSubmit}>
            <div id="sign-in-button"></div>
            {/* <PhoneInput */}

            <label>Mobile Number</label> <br />
            {/* for="phoneNumber"  */}
            <IntlTelInput
              containerClassName="intl-tel-input"
  inputClassName="form-control"
     name="mobile" placeholder="Enter Your Number" 
    input type="tel" value={this.state.phoneNumber}
       onChange={this.handleChange}
    
      />
            {/* <input type="tel" id="phone" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter Your Number" required onChange={this.handleChange} /> */}
            <div className="buttons">
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitOTP}>
            <label >Code</label> <br />
            {/* for="code" */}

            <input type="number" name="otp" placeholder="Enter The 6 Digit OTP" required onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <div className="buttons" >
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: If you dig into the [source](https://github.com/patw0929/react-intl-tel-input/blob/master/src/components/IntlTelInput.js#L1332-L1409) and look at the proptypes that the `IntlTelInput` component takes you'll find it doesn't take an `onChange` prop, but rather has an `onPhoneNumberChange` handler.

Comment: I tried this but it show the same error

Comment: Which one? You kind of mentioned more than 1 issue/error in your question. I was just helping with the first with accessing the `this.handleChange` handler. For the `phoneNumber` where is this error from? Is there a stacktrace telling you which line is the issue?

Comment: Both the error is same because i was calling  `phoneNumber` from `this.handleChange` and . i don't know to setup  intl-tel-input documentation is not working for me

Comment: Can you try to create a *running* codesandbox example with the above code you've an issue with that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: Sir this is the same code which run in my system but in codesandbox  it unable to send the sms I have installed all the dependency but it store the number in console but you can see my code in  codesandbox   https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-smoke-kjkdq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Taking a look now. Can you give me a brief recap and reproduction steps to cause the issue? The code in the CSB doesn't match 100% with your snippet, there's no `IntlTelInput` component rendered.

Comment: in this i have install the i react-intl-tel-input but not import in my code use because it was not working

Comment: But isn't that what your entire question is about, using the `IntlTelInput` component and getting it to work? Is that still your question/issue in this post?

Comment: This is my normal  code code where i want to add  the react-intl-tel-input or anything which work similar to that please help i am a beginner dont know much things

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-smoke-kjkdq?file=/src/App.js I have updated the IntlTelInput

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239726/discussion-between-mohammad-zeeshan-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

- There is no defined *initial* state so this is why accessing `this.state.phoneNumber` is throwing an error.
- The `IntlTelInput` component takes an `onPhoneNumberChange` handler that takes a validation status, current value, and country details as arguments instead of an `onChange` handler taking an `onChange` event object.

## Solution

Provide valid initial state for the component. In React class components `state` is simply a class property, it just needs to be defined.

```
state = {};
```

Create a new change handler specifically for the `IntlTelInput` component.

```
handlePhoneChange = (status, phoneNumber, country) => {
  this.setState({ phoneNumber });
};
```

Switch from `onChange` to `onPhoneNumberChange` event handler.

```
<IntlTelInput
  containerClassName="intl-tel-input"
  inputClassName="form-control"
  name="mobile"
  placeholder="Enter Your Number"
  input
  type="tel"
  value={this.state.phoneNumber}
  onPhoneNumberChange={this.handlePhoneChange}
/>
```

[image: Edit how-to-integrate-react-intl-tel-input]

Comment: It was showing the same error `×
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'phoneNumber')`

Comment: @MOHAMMADZEESHAN Adding the `state = {}` should have resolved that. Check this forked [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-integrate-react-intl-tel-input-rcus0).

Comment: I'm trying to add a custom parameter to onPhoneNumberChange but because of that status, phoneNumber, country show undefined.
Is there any way to add custom param to the function?

Comment: @danish It seems like you might have more going on than would be considered on-topic to this answer that is resolvable via comments.  This sounds like it is probably a good new on-topic post (*with [mcve]*). If you create a new post feel free to ping me here in another comment a link to the new post, and I can take a look when available.